GNOME Disks Unlock at System Start Up Debugging
I have been attempting to set my Micro SD card to automatically unlock once I login. However, it does not work as planned. Below is how I set up the encryption with GNOME Disks.
Would any of you know why this might not be decryption upon login?
OS: PureOS

